# How to run BIP reports through unix script

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

We have a requirement of running/Scheduling BIP reports through unix script.Obiee will be installed in the same unix box.

Could you please help me.I am not getting any clue on this.

Answer (score 1):

One sure shot way is to use BIP webservices. The BIP server has a generic WSDL which has a method called runReport & scheduleReport. The request message for these take a report name and parameters as input, and can be used to schedule delivery of reports. You can use these with wget to submit a report request from unix.

BIP itself has its own command line tools which can be used to schedule jobs : SASchInvoke .

Comment: Thanks a lot.Could you please help me with any website or any examples??

Comment: hey i got the methods for runReport.but how i will pass values as a parameter from unix box??